# Having difficulty in inserting data into postgres table using typescript, typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Unable to insert data into postgres table. Connection is working, post request is working, no error is showing, but input data is not inserted hence redirected into the same page again.

Data can be manullay inserted. And log in funtionality works.

**User.ts** entity

import { Entity, BaseEntity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm"

@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity {

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number

@Column({
    unique: true
})
username: string;

@Column()
password: string;

@Column({
    default: false
})
isAdmin: boolean;
```

}

**UserController.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../entities/User';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export class UserController {
    static async register(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const { username, password } = req.body;

        const userRepository = getRepository(User);

        // Check if a user with the same username already exists
        const existingUser = await userRepository.findOne({ where: { username } });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).render('register', { error: 'Username is already taken' });
        }

        if (!password) {
            return res.status(400).render('register', { error: 'Password is required' });
        }

        // Hash the password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        // Create a new user
        const user = userRepository.create({
            username: username,
            password: hashedPassword,
            isAdmin: true
        });
        await userRepository.save(user);

        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**routes.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import { UserController } from "./controller/UserController";

const app = express();
// app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

export const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (_, res) => {
    res.redirect('/register');
});

router.get('/register', (_, res) => {
    res.render('register', { error: null });
});

router.post('/register', UserController.register);
```